# Millions of rows in MongoDB with PHP. How can we retrieve and display it faster?

Tags: php, mongodb, performance, search

I have an application that stores company contact information and some related data.
This web application is built in PHP 7. The issue is that when I have millions of search results, the site becomes slower.

There is a pagination to navigate through the search results, and it is even more slower.

I saw apps like snowflake.com etc where they million rows are loaded in couple of seconds.
What technology are they using? What coding techniques and tools or JS libraries should I adopt?

Does migrating the "slow search results" page to NodeJS help? or to any other language would help?
Are there any improvements to do on the MongoDB? Does moving to ReactJS or AngularJS would help?

I really look forward to hear some real life experiences and advises on this so that I can implement it in my application.
Thank you.

Comment: Does your query return just the results to fill the page, e.g. using skip and limit or are you fetching all results and then extracting the required number? Does you query utilise a good index?

Comment: We are displaying the results as a listing based on search filter and currently it uses skip and limit for pagination. I tried the rowid > last id also but it needs sorting of entire results which also making it slower. Yes we are using indexes but we have 10+ filter fields and search can come in any combination which needs a lot of indexes with different combination.
If indexing is the best option then any suggestions to fulfill different search combinations?

Comment: Sounds like you have considered the obvious then. What access do you have to the server? Would you be able to install something like Solr: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/ With my one application I use a combination of database for normal crud operations and save certain items to Solr on update or create. Search is done through Solr and that returns a reference to the database row. Search results from Solr are displayed and if clicked on it can open the item from the database.